# How to scrape a website hosted on another country server?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

I am creating a web scraper using python (beautifulsoup4). I want to fetch the content of "Hackerearth" website but since I have hosted my web scraper on heroku (US server), so it's fecthing the US version of hackerearth and not the version based on my country. So I want to fetch the website version based on my country.

```
url = "https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The website/webserver detect your (or your bots) language/country either by headers (e.g. [Content-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language), [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language))
or by the clients' IP-Address

Headers can be [faked](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) easily. To fake the clients' IP-Address you need a proxy of this country.

Comment: I am currently in India. I tried using proxy but that didn't work. Actually I don't know exactly how to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your edited cookie as follow.

```
cookies ={'aep_usuc_f':'region=US&site=glo&b_locale=en_US&c_tp=USD'}
url = "https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: I want the Indian version of website, so should I replace US with IN?

Comment: try with india region and site code. it would probably work